# h2 database Junit test case failing on executing 'INSERT IGNORE INTO ..' query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have this Spring Boot Application, where I have used h2 database to cover Junit test case. Everything is working fine until I have this new scenario where I need to execute a MySql query using jdbcTemplate.

The jdbcTemplate is to execute below query

'INSERT **IGNORE** INTO someTableName ......'

It is working fine when running the service and from postman getting successful response but jUnit test cases are started failing after this change.

I have used @DataJdbcTest annotation to support h2 database based jUnit test case.

I am pretty much sure the issue is due to **IGNORE** keyword in sql query, but I need to know if there is simple solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try h2's MySQL [Compatibility Mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility).

From their docs:

> INSERT IGNORE is partially supported and may be used to skip rows with duplicate keys if ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not specified.